# initialize an interface with another interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

Actually I have 2 interfaces :

```
export class Part {
    constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public part?: string,
        public type?: string

    ) {}
}

export class Session {
    constructor(
      public genre?: string,
      public ordre_interface?: number,
      public nb_serie?: number,
      public id?: number,
      public part_a?: Part,
      public part_b?: Part,
  
    ) {}

}
```

Then inside my main .ts file, I import those 2 interfaces, and I initialize I `new Session()` in an array. But for part_a and part_b which should be another empty Object with the `class Part`, I got only undefined, or I'd like to get an empty Object.

```
EXOS = new Session();
```

here if I console.log EXOS I got = `[genre: undefined, id: undefined... part_a: undefined...]`

Or for `part_a`, I'd like an object with my `class Part()`

To do so, inside my constructor I do :

```
this.EXOS.part_a = new Part();
```

Can I initialize EXOS with a new session and inside it a new Part() for part_a and part_b directly from the initialisation phase instead of doing it inside the constructor ?

Thank you

Comment: What is the "initialisation phase" if *not* the constructor? Have you considered default values?

Comment: what I call initilization phase is when I declare my variable at the beginning of the code, before the constructor. Answer below is perfect.

Comment: @Tom The initialization phase is, generally, the phase between `{` and `}` in the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give default values directly in the declaration of the constructor.

```js
export class Part {
    constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public part?: string,
        public type?: string

    ) {}
}

export class Session {
    constructor(
      public genre?: string,
      public ordre_interface?: number,
      public nb_serie?: number,
      public id?: number,
      public part_a: Part = new Part(),
      public part_b: Part = new Part(),
  
    ) {}

}
```

Those are not interfaces but classes.